# cascading class properties vb.net

Tags: vb.net

This 3 classes structure is a simplified view of my code :

Base class :

```
Public Class A

    Public x As Integer

    Protected Function G() as Integer
       Return x
    End Function

    Protected Sub S(value as Integer)
         x = value
    End Sub

    Public Function Test()
         Return x + 10
    End Function

End Class
```

Subclasses :

```
Public Class B

    Inherits A

    Public Property Prop As Integer
        Get
            Return G()
        End Get
        Set(ByVal Value As Integer)
            S(Value)
        End Set
    End Property

End Class

Public Class C

    Inherits A

    Public InnerB As New B

End Class
```

The goal is to be able to code something like that :

```
Dim B1 as New B
Dim C1 as New C

B1.Prop = 10
C1.InnerB.Prop = 20 'the "x" member inherited from A takes the value 20 for the InnerB object but not for the C1 object.

MsgBox(B1.Test()) ' returns 20. Works!
MsgBox(C1.Test()) 'returns 10 instead of 30.
```

Is it possible to fill the inherited "x" member from C by calling the "prop" from it's inner class B ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you set

```
C1.InnerB.Prop = 20
```

It actually does

```
C1.InnerB.x = 20
```

When you call

```
C1.Test()
```

It will access

```
C1.x
```

instead of

```
C1.InnerB.x
```

You'll need to call

```
MsgBox(C1.InnerB.Test())
```

Or override the Test function

```
Public Class C
    Inherits A

    Public InnerB As New B

    Public Overrides Function Test()
         Return InnerB.Test()
    End Function

End Class
```

But what you are doing is.... weird

Comment: Thank you for your answer, it works for my example, but not for my real code : The C class contains in fact many inner classes, and all inherits from the A class. To explain what i am doing, it's basically an ORM. Class A represents the database connection manager (contains recordset and movenext/previous methods etc ... ). Each B Class represents a database table and each property represents a field. The C class is an object containing all database tables, I use this class to manage sql "SELECT" request on several tables. Like you said, maybe it's "weird", and another logic may exists.

Comment: @kloug I'm sorry if I can't help you more. It's a bit hard to understand what the problem is.

Comment: Ok I found a solution. Problem was in fact how to access outer class member from inner class. This thread helped me [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8692475/how-to-get-a-value-inside-parent-class-from-child-class-in-nested-classes)